# How to achieve persistent storage in NeDB?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I tried NeDB in node-webkit it's working fine on in memory data but not able to store in persistent storage.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Needs more info- have you looked at [nedb db loading](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#creatingloading-a-database), specifically the `inMemoryOnly` and `autoload` options?

Comment: at last I found the database is created in some other directory
the package is at : C:\Users\Dinesh\Programs\Node-Webkit\FrameLess
the nw.exe is at : C:\Users\Dinesh\Programs\Node-Webkit\Package
the database is saved at some weird location : C:\Users\Dinesh\AppData\Local\FrameLess\nedb-data

Comment: is there a way to create the data base at the nw.exe folder without giving the absolute path or is there a function node-webkit to the location of nw.exe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

definitely no node-webkit or nedb expert but this is how I did it and it worked.

As already mentioned by mvanderw in the comments, definitely make sure to check the autoload option.

This is for example my configuration for a simple node-webkit/ angular todo app:

```
var Datastore = require('nedb'),                                                                                                                                              
    path = require('path'),
    db = new Datastore({ filename: path.join(require('nw.gui').App.dataPath, 'todo.db'), autoload: true });
```

When I restart the app, all todos are still there and I'm ready to go.

Hope this helps

*Edit:* 
Example as requested by Scott

```
var Datastore = require('nedb'), 
path = require('path'),
db = new Datastore({
  filename:path.join(require('nw.gui').App.dataPath, 'todo.db'),
  autoload: true
}); 

var todoServices = angular.module('todoServices', []);

todoServices.factory('Todo', function($q) {
  return { 
    getAll: function(){ 
      var defer = $q.defer();
      db.find({ 
        //...some criteria
      },
      function(err, docs) {
        defer.resolve(docs);
      });
      return defer.promise;
    }, //...moar code
  }
});
```

Something like this...

Comment: by any chance have you published the code for your todo app? I'm trying to integrate nedb with my node-webkit app and the lack of functioning examples is really limiting

Comment: ehm... maybe ask a Stack Question and link to it so I can post with proper formatting :)

Comment: Added example to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Users\Dinesh\AppData\Local\FrameLess\nedb-data` is where `node-webkit` uncompressed the app; it means that your app has been packaged as `.nw`, which is a smarter zip file. As a consequence it must be unzipped in a tmp folder to execute, which is why you found your db in `AppData`.

In your developer tool you can always know which folder your app has been unzipped into by typing: `process.env`. Your `TMPDIR` property is where your db sits in (`TMPDIR` is a Mac OS X property, it might be named differently on Windows).

You can execute your `nw` app without packaging it. Basically you can drag your folder onto `nw.exe`; or typing `nw.exe yourAppFolder`; or package your app as `.nw`, as you did.

Read the following guideline once again: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-run-apps